# SQL Grouping to show sum

Tags: sql-server-2008

I Have below data returned from my code :

```
Part        QTYPerUnit   Multiplier
PN1         8            1
PN1         72           2
PN1         40           3
PN1         16           4
PN1         24           6
```

I need the results in new table to be grouped in 1 row and show the total:

```
Part        QTYPerUnit   Multiplier
PN1         160          16
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply putting following query for the given data will give you desired output

```
SELECT SUM([QTYPerUnit]) QTYPerUnit, SUM([Multiplier]) Multiplier FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```

If you have multiple parts, you can use `GROUP BY`  `[Part]` like following.

```
SELECT [Part], SUM([QTYPerUnit]) QTYPerUnit, SUM([Multiplier]) Multiplier 
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
GROUP BY [Part]
```

To insert into a new table, you can do it in following way.

```
INSERT INTO [NEW_TABLE]([Part],[QTYPerUnit],[Multiplier])
SELECT [Part],SUM([QTYPerUnit]), SUM([Multiplier]) 
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
GROUP BY [Part]
```

Or simpally

```
SELECT [Part],SUM([QTYPerUnit]) QTYPerUnit, SUM([Multiplier]) Multiplier 
INTO [NEW_TABLE]
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
GROUP BY [Part]
```

Above statement will crate a new table and will insert the values. It will throw error if the table already exists.

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/GXA86152)</kbd>**